# NEMA 14-30 outlet Installation question

Tags: receptacle, 240v

[image]

I need to install a NEMA 14-30 outlet in my garage. It will be installed within 2 to 3 feet of the breaker box. My question is for esthetics. Can I run the wire from the bottom of the box through a pipe over the wall and install the box below the panel or do I need to run the wire up through the ceiling and then come down to install at a particular height? Where would you run the wire and install the outlet for a professional looking job?

Thanks in advance for your input.

UPDATE: Thanks for all the input. Ive decided to go with a NEMA 14-30 on a 30 amp breaker and 10/3 wire. Everything went well.[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!   Wait.  Is your desirable outlet location on the other side of this wall??  Which side of the wall are you concerned with aesthetics on, this side or the other side?

Comment: I am adding the outlet to the right or left of the panel. I am thinking the most professional looking job would be have the wires going up to ceiling and then coming down thru a conduit down to the same height as the other regular outlets. But it would be easier just coming down from the bottom of the breaker panel. I am just wondering what would a professional electrician would do? Thx for your input.

Answer (score 2):

#### Conduit

Any wires below a certain height need to be protected. In a typical wood studs + drywall setup, that can be running the wires inside the wall, protected with metal plates in certain locations. However, with a block wall you will run the wires outside the wall, which means running the wires through **conduit**. Once you are using conduit, you can run the wires pretty much any way you want to, as the conduit protects the wires wherever they go. A few things to keep in mind:

- You definitely want to use individual **wires**, not **cable**, as that will be much easier to push through conduit.
- There are limits on how many turns in a section of conduit. That makes it easier to pull wires through, but is less of a concern with a very short run - but you do have to follow the rules.
- If you are using this for an electric car charger, you may want to upsize for a future larger charger. The breaker and receptacle need to be sized to match each other and to match the specifications of the charger. The wire can be larger to support a larger charger in the future. On the other hand, since you will be using conduit, you can always replace the wires later relatively easily.
- You *may* need GFCI protection. In this case (unlike 5-15 and 5-20), the breaker is the place to do it. As noted in comments by others, it looks like GFCI is a requirement in a garage only for < 150V - i.e., your typical 120V 15A and 20A receptacles but *not* required for 240V (dryer, car charger, etc.). (I'm not a professional, and I don't have a garage, so this isn't something I'm that familiar with.)

Comment: You can fit  4 THHN #10 AWG in 1/2" conduit but not 4 #6 AWG  so use at least 3/4" EMT.

Comment: Since this will be in a garage it will have to be GFCI protected in the panel

Comment: @JACK And for a few feet, the cost difference between 1/2" and 3/4" is peanuts.

Comment: Could someone provide a reference for 240v needing gfci in a garage?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I commented on this due to the fact that it was in a garage. I could be mistaken.

Comment: Looks like 210.8(A) requires dwelling unit 125v single phase 15 an 20A, in garages, and (B) other  than dwelling units 150v to ground 100 amps or less. He said "my garage", so I didn't think that applied. But was looking for some additional requirement I may have missed.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to run the pipe up, then come down, there is no specific mounting height required. There are accessibility rules, and many appliances have instructions included with the appliance that prohibit using extension cords. The instructions are part of the UL listing.

A Professional looking job is subjective, extra bends in the conduit will be the biggest eye sore. Personally only a couple feet away I would just put a 90 out of the bottom corner and run straight to the outlet location, just at least far enough enough to not encroach on the 30" access area in front of the panel.

I don't understand that the NEC requires GFCI (or AFCI) for a 240v receptacle in a dwelling unit garage.

Comment: Any reason they couldn't come directly out the side, even?

Comment: You could come out the side, my hesitation  is you have to drill a hole larger than the conduit to accommodate the fitting and any error at drilling through the furring would be more visible than drilling through the bottom.

Comment: I do wonder if there's a furring piece at the bottom of this box as well...

Answer (score 0):

I'd pick any mounting point for the receptacle that I pleased; however, I'd try to arrange it so the mounting point aligns with one of the knockouts on the panel, e.g. on its sides.  It has many on its sides; for some strange reason someone framed around it, but I'd go right through it. Regardless, I'd connect with a 3/4" EMT conduit bent no more than needed; out the bottom I'd use an LB conduit body for a sharp turn, otherwise a pipe bend.

Then I would either put the mini-S-turns on the conduit so it runs flush against the wall, or just mount it to the wall with spacers every foot or so.

Paint the EMT and the box wall colors.